# AngularJs select item not setting correct text on first select

Tags: angularjs

I Have a select box set as so:

```
<select id="Supplier" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.SelectedSupplier" ng-options="S.Name for S in vm.Suppliers"></select>
```

When the page loads up the selection in the select box is blank. So far so good. But, when I select one of the options, regardless of its index, the text value in the select box gets set to the 1st option, but, the model bound by ng-model is set to the correct value.

This only happens on the first select attempt though, subsequent select attempts have the text in the select box match the suppliers name at the selected index.

I hope that makes sense, any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: To me, it doesn't make sense, unfortunately. Please clarify, by telling us what vm.Suppliers contains( give example data), what you're doing with the select box, what you expect to happen and what happens instead. A plunkr would also be helpful.

Comment: Are you using ui-select2. I know that this a known bug with ui-select2 and ng-options? http://plnkr.co/edit/g1G0PEJfNQdmZbiJSLgE?p=preview

Comment: Can you paste your Supplier array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regards to pkozlowski if  ng-model doesn't exist in a set of options passed to ng-options the  empty option is generated and added to select . That  will  prevent accidental model selection: AngularJS can see that the initial model is either undefined or not in the set of options and don't want to decide model value on its own.

please see here :http://plnkr.co/edit/imjLXBmGpZReZ63KNWlg?p=preview
just add default option to select like in example and that will fix your problem

```
<select id="Supplier" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.SelectedSupplier" ng-options="S.Name for S in vm.Suppliers">
          <option style="display:none" value=""></option>  //<-here

       </select>
```